# How to setup the right config in two nested symfony applications?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, web, doctrine

I have two symfony application sf1 and sf3 (sf3 inside sf1) .i start with SF1 because the entry points are in sf1 (**DocumentRoot "${PORTALROOT}/web"**
) and sf1 need a database already configured to be loaded. [home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXmJc.png) .

I created a Bundle inside sf3 (localhost/setup)[setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqwmx.png) for the installation of the application and the setting up of the database ... the problem is i can t load the page **localhost/setup** because we don t have a database yet.

**here is my vhost.conf**

Listen 8000

Define PORTALROOT "C:/workspace/portal/openbeeportal"

```
DocumentRoot "${PORTALROOT}/web"

<Directory "${PORTALROOT}/web/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Includes -ExecCGI

    <Files autosign.php>
        AuthName "Intranet"
        AuthType SSPI
        SSPIAuth On
        SSPIAuthoritative On
        SSPIOfferBasic Off
        SSPIPerRequestAuth On
        SSPIOmitDomain Off
        require valid-user
    </Files>

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        # Apache 2.4
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        # Apache 2.2
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </IfModule>***vhost***
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you add the database settings in the config / parameter / framework file in your SF3 project?

Comment: yes sure i did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is through an entry point that only charges **SF3**
 via a **dedicated appkernel** for sf3 ,
[Multiple applications with Symfony](https://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2)